# non stationary series, not sure how to remove it

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, stationarity

[image: Series 1]

[image: Series 2]

I have these two time series, the Adfuller test says there non stationary. I don't know how should I go about making them stationary without resorting to modelling techniques?

Comment: Are you sure the test says they are nonstationary? I would be a little surprised by that. What are the test results?

Comment: p_value=0.6!! for accessories and 0.7 for bookcases

Comment: Interesting... Perhaps the specification of the model used in the test is inadequate.

Comment: What would *not* "resorting to modeling techniques" mean?  After all, "stationary" is a concept that makes sense *only* within the ambit of a certain kind of time series model.

Comment: @RichardHardy I really don't think so. I am sure I applied it correctly.

Comment: @RichardHardy I am attaching here the series. You can test it yourself and plot it and see. I still to this moment don't know why I have that discrepancy. This is the series in csv https://we.tl/t-XJrPQocKKT (WeTransfer company). I would very much appreciate the insight of why this is the case.

Comment: @whuber I meant not yet have done SARIMA for example to make it stationary.